# d3.js / svg - how to dynamically append text to my arcs

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, expressionengine, data-visualization

I am trying to complete the last bit of a d3 project which dynamically creates these blue arcs, over which I need to place arc text, as shown in this image:

[image]

The image above is something I've done by placing the arc text statically, through trial and error, but I want to place it dynamically, based on the blue arcs which sit beneath the text. This is the code that dynamically creates the arcs:

```
var groupData = data_group.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(nodes.filter(function(d) { console.log(d.__data__.key); return (d.key=='Employers' ||{exp:channel:entries category="13" backspace="2"} d.key == '{url_title}' ||{/exp:channel:entries}) && d.children; }))
    .enter().append("group")
    .attr("class", "group");

arc_group.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(groupData[0])
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", groupArc)
    .attr("class", "groupArc")
    .style("fill", "#1f77b4")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.5);
```

The {exp:} content is preparsed data I'm pulling from my content management system in expression engine if it looks confusing.

So, I have my arcs. Now you'll notice in the groupData code block I have a console.log statement, that will give me the names I want to appear in the arc text:

```
console.log(d.__data__.key);
```

Now, the code I was using to place the arc text statically was this:

```
var arcData = [
  {aS: 0, aE: 45,rI:radius - chartConfig.linePadding + chartConfig.arcPadding,rO:radius - chartConfig.linePadding + chartConfig.textPadding-chartConfig.arcPadding}
];

var arcJobsData = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(arcData[0].rI).outerRadius(arcData[0].rO).startAngle(degToRad(1)).endAngle(degToRad(15));
var g = d3.select(".chart").append("svg:g").attr("class","arcs");
var arcJobs = d3.select(".arcs").append("svg:path").attr("d",arcJobsData).attr("id","arcJobs").attr("class","arc");
g.append("svg:text").attr("x",3).attr("dy",15).append("svg:textPath").attr("xlink:href","#arcJobs").text("JOBS").attr("class","arcText"); //x shifts x pixels from the starting point of the arc. dy shifts the text y units from the top of the arc
```

And in this above code, the only thing left that I should need to do is dynamically assign an ID to the arcs, and then reference that ID in the xlink:href attribute, as well as replace the text("JOBS") with text that pulls from d.**data__key. Given the code above which dynamically creates the arcs, and given that I know how to dynamically create and retrieve the text I want to place in the arcs using d.__data**.key, I should be able to finish this thing off, but I can't figure out how write code in d3 that will take the data and place it in the arcs. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. Changed the structure of things a bit so it made a little more sense, but essentially what I did is this:

```
var groupData = data_group.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(nodes.filter(function(d) { return (d.key=='Employers' ||{exp:channel:entries category="13" backspace="2"} d.key == '{url_title}' ||{/exp:channel:entries}) && d.children; }))
    .enter().append("group")
    .attr("class", "group"); //MH - why do we need this group - these elements are empty. Shouldn't this just be an array? Find out how to delete the svg elements without getting rid of the data, which is needed below.


  var groupArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(ry - 177)
    .outerRadius(ry - 157)
    .startAngle(function(d) { return (findStartAngle(d.__data__.children)-2) * pi / 180;})
    .endAngle(function(d) { console.log(d.__data__.key); return (findEndAngle(d.__data__.children)+2) * pi / 180});

  var arc_and_text = arc_group.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(groupData[0])
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class","arc_and_text");

  var arc_path = arc_and_text.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", groupArc)
    .attr("class", "groupArc")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "arc" + i; })
    .style("fill", "#1f77b4")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.5); //MH: (d.__data__.key) gives names of groupings

  var arc_text = arc_and_text.append("text")
    .attr("class","arc_text")
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("dy", 15);

  arc_text.append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#arc" + i; })
    .attr("class","arc_text_path")
    .style("fill","#ffffff")
    .text(function(d, i) { return d.__data__.key; });
```

D3 still mystifies me a bit, and I'm sure this code could be much improved, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

You should give [this blog post on nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) a read; I believe it'll explain what you're trying to do.

Here's the gist. When you add data to your selection, assign the selection to a variable:

```
var g = data_group.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(nodes.filter(function(d) { /* stuff */ }));
```

That way, you can perform subselections on it, which will receive a single element of the data bound to your `g` selection. You can use this to add your arcs and text:

```
g.enter().append('group') // Question: Are you sure you mean 'group' here?
    .attr('class', 'group')

g.selectAll('g.arc')
    .data(function(d, i) { return d; })
  enter().append('path')
     // Setup the path here

g.selectAll('text')
    .data(function(d, i) { return d; })
  .enter().append('text')
    .attr('text', function(d) { return d.__data__.key })
```

The functions that are being used to do data binding in the nested selections (i.e., the `g.selectAll()`s) are being passed a single *element* of the data attached to `g` as `d`, and `i` is its index.

Comment: Hmmmm this solution is not working for me. However, when I wrap the single element of the data in array it works.